# booting without full network configuration 13.10

Tags: network-manager, mobile-broadband, connman

Recently I tried to install connman which removed network manager and some other dependencies. Now I cannot connect to any network, either wireless or broadband. I have tried multiple solutions from this forum but nothing seems to work. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First boot Ubuntu live disk.
- Click on try Ubuntu option on startup.It will load the desktop.
- Open up the terminal by pressing ctrl+Alt+T.
- Run the below commands to download the `network-manager` package,

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  apt-get download network-manager
  ```
- It will download `network-manager` package and also some related packages in your home directory.All the packages are in `.deb` format.
- Copy all the .deb packages to your system which was not able to connect to the internet.
- Then install all the deb packages by running,

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i filename.deb
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have network manager try to manual configure network.
Link to official documentation is https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/network-configuration.html.